# Animated div sliding from bottom within another div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have, using `CSS`, on hover, a div that slides from the bottom of the div to 50% high up the div and stick in which I can have text. My coding so far is below:

```
<div id="cell1">
    <div style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999; background-color: #CCC; height: 395px;">
        <div align="center">Image Here</div>
    </div> 
    <p></p>
    <div style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999; background-color: #CCC; height: 395px;">Article2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why the javascript and jquery tag if you want a clean css solution?

Comment: @TimRücker just incase somebody that knows more about jquery and javascript than me, tells me that javascript is the only way to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by absolutely positioning the `div` you want to slide in within the parent container, then transition its `max-height` from zero to 50%.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/bPGPL/1/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position:relative; /* important */
    height:200px; /* can be anything */
    width:200px; /* can be anything */
    background:red; /* not important */
}
div div {
    position:absolute; /* important */
    bottom:0; /* important */
    max-height:0; /* important */
    overflow:hidden; /* important */
    background:blue;  /* not important */
    transition:max-height 250ms ease-in; /* important */
}
div:hover div {
    max-height:50%; /* important */
}
```

Comment: thank you so much this is perfect, but I am new to all of this, if I call the div inside that has transition applied #slideup and maybe have the main div as #slideupholder, how would I change the css to suit? This is more for me to learn than anything else :) your so so good though, I hope I am as good as you after my course :)